# Splunk not recognizing regex

Tags: json, regex, parsing, splunk

I'm struggling to make a regex work with splunk. It works with regex 101, but splunk doesn't seem to recognize it!

**Regex:** `\"([\w]+)\":([^,}]+)`

**Log entry:**

```
May 20 12:22:21 127.0.0.1 {"rootId": "AXIxikL8ao-yaSvA", "requestId": "f6a873jkjjkjk:-8000:5738", 
"details": {"flag": false, "title": "task 1", "status": "Waiting", "group": "", "order": 0}, 
"operation": "Creation", "objectId": "AXIyCN5Oao-H5aYyaSvd", "startDate": 1589977341890, 
"objectType": "case_task", "base": true, "object": {"_routing": "AXIxikL8ao-H5aYyaSvA", "flag": 
false, "_type": "case_task", "title": "task 1", "createdAt": 1589977341516, "_parent": "AXIxikL8ao- 
H5aYyaSvA", "createdBy": "user", "_id": "AXIyCN5Oao-H5aYyaSvd", "id": "AXIyCN5Oao-H5aYyaSvd", 
"_version": 1, "order": 0, "status": "Waiting", "group": ""}}
```

**Regex 101 link:**
https://regex101.com/r/XBuz9Y/2/

I suspect splunk may have a different regex syntax, but i don't really know how to adapt it.

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps use a json parser instead if there is one available.

Comment: @Thefourthbird the thing is that splunk inserts the datetime and host values at indexing time at the beginning of the log, which turns the log into an invalid json and thereforei cant use the default parser.

Comment: Then split the datetime and the json part and load the json part using a parser?

Comment: @Thefourthbird i've done that! The regex is in my question! The problem is that i can't seem to adapt to splunk's "own" regex language

Comment: It seems to be using pcre, did you use the right [syntax](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/Rex)? Can you add the code that you have tried to the question so it is easier for people to help you spotting or resolving the issue.

Comment: @Thefourthbird yes! i used regex 101 pcre (PHP) validator! i've introduced the log and the regex expression that i want to use to parse the log.

Comment: You need `"(?<key>\w+)":(?<value>[^,}]+)`, i.e. **named capturing groups**.

Comment: Does `... | rex "\"(?<key>\w+)\":(?<value>[^,}]+)"` work as expected?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your regex only parses the first field of the json

Comment: Yeah, it is default, use `... | rex max_match=1000 "\"(?<key>\w+)\":(?<value>[^,}]+)"`. You may set `max_match` to a higher value if you expect more than 1000 matches. Or, try `max_match=0`, it can probably extract unlimited amount of matches

Comment: why not use Splunk's native JSON handler, and then pull apart the multivalue fields with `mvexpand` or `spath`?

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
... | rex max_match=0 "\"(?<key>\w+)\":(?<value>[^,}]+)"
```

Here, `max_match=0` will enable *multiple matching* (by defauly, if you do not use `max_match` parameter, only the first match is returned) and the [*named capturing groups*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) (here, see `(?<key>...)` and `(?<value>...)`) will ensure field creation.

See more about the [Splunk `rex` command](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.0.3/SearchReference/Rex).

Comment: However, if i want to keep the field names how can i proceed? Here, it only specifies a list of keys and values instead of parsing all the fields and values

Comment: @laker02 Looks like that is the only way in Splunk.

Answer (score 0):

Grab the JSON fragment of your event using `rex`, and then use `spath` to do the extraction.

```
rex field=_raw "^[^{]+(?<json>.*)" | spath input=json
```

This should extract the JSON fields with the appropriate structure.